# Bay Speaker Panel Installation

Tags: computer-building

I purchased a bay speaker panel that has a molex connector and a sound connector. Do I need to run the sound connector through my tower and somehow out the back into the IO panel? Or is there supposed to be a place on my motherboard for it to connect to? This is a replacement for normal desktop speakers for me to save desk space.

**Edit**:

Is there an adapter for the sound cable to the mother board? If so; what is it called?

[image]

I am using the [asus z87 pro mother board](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z87PRO/) and [HAF 922 tower](http://www.coolermaster.com/case/mid-tower/haf-922/).

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What does the instructions tell you to do? If you give some product details, pictures, or something maybe we can give you an informed answer. At this point we don't know enough to be able to help you much.

Comment: @CharlieRB I will include a picture of the cable, but the biggest problem is the fact that no directions came in the package, and I can't any directions online.

Comment: Some motherboards have (additional) internal connections for audio, no they rarely would be a 3.5mm stereo jack, and yes you can buy or make various adapters to connect to them, so What motherboard do you have?  Lots of cases have front jacks for headphone mic, does your case have that too?  Lots more info could still be provided.

Comment: @Psycogeek I included my tower and mother board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess it would go through a suitable hole, like a notched expansion slot cover and to a sound output at the back of the PC, just like normal speakers.

My case has something like this for passing through a USB port

[image], and I've seen older motherboards with a pair of holes for passthrough. You might also be able to get a slot cover for water cooling with holes already there, or [just bend the end that's not bent out of the way to pass through a cable](http://www.computershopper.com/feature/75-pc-building-tips-slots-and-cards)

[image]

If your cable is too short, just get a 3.5mm extension cable to extend your current audio cable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and included pictures. I have a few extra slots on the back of my tower but when i open them it seems like overkill space to slip a small wire through. I will look at using the water cooling slots that come with the tower. I will also include a picture of the back of my tower shortly.